# Shell script run through runtime.exec() behaves differently than if I run it through terminal

Tags: android

I have this snippet of shell script:

```
am start -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity -d /sdcard/movie.mp4
sleep 5
input keyevent 4
```

This script basically reads as follow:
 1. Open the gallery application to start movie.mp4
 2. Sleep 5 seconds
 3. Press back key

When I run this script through adb shell, things work out as expected which is the video plays only for the first 5 seconds and then the back key is pressed which essentially quits the gallery app.

However, when I run this though runtime.exec()
The gallery does start, but then nothing else happen. It seems like the system prevents me from running the script when the application is in the background.
Anybody happens to know any work around? Or is there any way to use INTENT to achieve the same result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script run by an application runs as the application userid, which does not have the extra 
debug privileges that the adb shell (running as shell or even root) does.

For security reasons, applications are not supposed to be able to feed fake keystrokes to other applications and especially not to the system itself.

Perhaps instead of backing out of the gallery, you should try to start something else with an Intent.